# Mysql Connection not established

Tags: mysql, heidisql

Everytime I try to Open my HeidiSQL this error shows up[image]

What Should I do?

Comment: mysql service start?

Comment: @VaghaniJanak,  yes, I just installed it and tried to open it.

Comment: No no HeidiSQL is a mysql client. so first start mysql service then after try.

Comment: @VaghaniJanak how do I do that?

Comment: solved this error??